# VS2008 with SP1 seems to have no connectivity

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet-connection, visual-studio-2008

My machine has connectivity, everything is fine except for Visual Studio 2008. It can't get news feeds or more importantly connect to Team Foundation Server.

Has anyone ever seen this?

Comment: Check firewall and proxy settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a faulty setting in my machine.config